# chrome v 32 - html elements size issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

After the chrome 32 update, the width of the `html` elements (`input`, `select`,..)
defined by a `css` with these properties does not work:

```
position:absolute;
left:10px;
right:20px;
```

In chrome 31 and all others browsers it works.

Look at this with chrome 32

http://jsfiddle.net/EAkLb/7/

Comment: I have also tested, that's right

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome and FF here but Opera and Safari stretch the input.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what W3C says as the correct way of rendering input elements (I said I guess and I dindn't put the W3C spec link because I didn't found the official link for it)

A simple workarround is to create container div with the position absolute and the left and right attributes and create an input inside with width: 100%;

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        right:20px;
    }
    .container input {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

like in http://jsfiddle.net/pjK8s/1/

If you need to put padding than you need to style the container to looks like the input and let the input be transparent

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        right:20px;
        padding: 1px 8px;
        margin: 2px 0px;
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    }
    .container input {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: transparent;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

like in http://jsfiddle.net/Vyj22/1/