# Sudden cross-browser anomalies with absolute positioned widths

Tags: html, css, webkit

Consider the following code:

```
<div>
    <input type='text' />
</div>
```

...

```
div {
    width:300px;
    background:#DDD;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
}
input {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

A couple of months ago, this would have produced something like this fairly reliably:
[image]

Now, the width looks a mess in the latest versions of Chrome & IE: http://jsfiddle.net/eY5uj/1/
[image]

However, this method still works fine cross-browser for many other elements like `<p>` for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eY5uj/2/

**2 questions:**

1. What is going on here?
2. Is there any workaround (short of removing `position:absolute` and setting padding on the parent div?)

Comment: Related (or might actually be a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450316/html-input-element-ignores-css-leftright-properties. Actually I'm pretty sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284087/strange-behaviour-when-absolute-positioning-an-input-with-both-left-and-right-cs is a duplicate. I can't see how this has "changed" recently in IE. Chrome I could understand as that is updated and maybe previous behaviour was actually a bug.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284087/strange-behaviour-when-absolute-positioning-an-input-with-both-left-and-right-cs using CSS left+right _was_ working in Chrome 26. It is definitely different in my Chrome 34 so was probably a (now fixed) bug.

Comment: Thanks andyb - lots of interesting info in those links. It was definitely working in chrome until very recently so it makes sense that it was a bugfix. It's just unusual that they would intentionally make one element behave differently than all others.

Comment: Hmmmm, seems to be similar to the issue recently asked in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148540/chrome-v-32-html-elements-size-issue#comment31830974_21148540. Possible Chrome bug?